# seeing a blank screen after using Firebase in iOS iphone 13 OS 16.3 and lower versions

Tags: ios, firebase, progressive-web-apps

as per documentation we have configured firebase in PWA and build it, also enabled it as per steps given, we can see only firebase registeration token but blank screen after notification permission popup.

anybody able to resolve this issue on pwa app , please let us know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I would presume that it's strictly a UI problem. I don't think there's enough information in the question to find the issue.

Comment: hi @lazarevzubov, its pwa app, its working fine on android device, for IOS firebase given seperate steps to follow to integrate FCM messgaing, we followed same, we are not getting any error in console but except blank screen.